# 15.04: Keyboard layout changing

Tags: keyboard

I have my keyboard layout set to Irish and it is my only choice in the Input sources to use. What I find is that every now and then the keyboard layout revert to a Mac layout. I am running Ubuntu on a Mac Pro.

I think the cause of this is some of the updates changing the layout.

When I check the text entry settings what the key produces on the map is different to what is produced in a text editor or terminal.

Comment: Marked as low importance since two years ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272

Answer (score 0):

This happens every time I logout now. I've added a second text input and switch back and forth returns my keyboard layout to the desired setting.